# Mostrar dato agrupado en una columna Datatable

Tags: laravel, ajax, datatables

tengo una funcion que mediante una consulta sql me trae los SERVICIOS asociados a un técnico (siempre van a ser 2, uno variable y uno fijo (ACTIVOS)), esto lo paso a un datatable en una vista y me funciona, pero como se pueden dar cuenta siempre me saldran 2 filas por tecnico (por los 2 servicios que tendran asociados):
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Entonces lo que busco es que en el DataTable se muestre una fila por tecnico y en la columna Servicios pueda mostrar los dos servicios que tenga el tecnico...

Tengo la consulta asi en el controlador:

```
public function data(){
        //$tecnico = Tecnico::select('id', 'nombre_primario')->get();
        $tecnico = DB::table('tecnicos as tecnico')
        ->join('tecnico_servicios as servtec' , 'servtec.tecnico_id' , 'tecnico.id')
        ->join('servicios as servicio' , 'servicio.id' , 'servtec.servicio_id')
        ->select('tecnico.id', 'tecnico.nombre_primario','tecnico.nombre_secundario', 'tecnico.ape_pat', 'tecnico.ape_mat',
        'tecnico.num_doc', 'servicio.servicio')
        ->get();
        //->groupBy('id');

        //dd($tecnico);

        return datatables()->of($tecnico)
        //->addColumn('ver', '<a href="{{ route(\'empresa.show\', $id)}}">' .('Ver'). '</a>')
       /*  ->addColumn('accions', 'personal.funcionario.datatable.tec')
        ->rawColumns(['accions']) */
        ->toJson();
    }
```

El script html en la vista lo tengo asi:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tecnicos').DataTable({
         destroy: true,
        "ajax": "{{route('tecnicos.dataTable')}}",
        "columns":[
            {data: 'id'},
            {data: 'nombre_primario'},
            {data: 'nombre_secundario'},
            {data: 'ape_pat'},
            {data: 'ape_mat'},
            {data: 'num_doc'},
            {data: 'servicio'},
            {data: 'accions'}
        ],
        "language": {
            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "zeroRecords": "No hay Registros por mostrar",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No records available",
            "infoFiltered": "(Filtrado de _MAX_ registros totales)",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "paginate":{
            "next": "Siguiente",
            "previous" : "Anterior"
            },
         }
        });
    });
```

Y el agrupamiento lo realiza ok cuando veo el dd:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][2]][2]

Como podría resolver este problema? sera que no hago bien el agrupamiento?

Saludos a todos
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5IFg.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhPkf.png

Answer (score 0):

elimina el id no es un dato relevante para el usuario ni para ti dado que ya va en la columna de acciones, agrupa por nombre_primario y groupBy va antes del get();
create una columna(addColumn) y concatenale los servicio